# Google Maps: get latitude and longitude from map element

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map and I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude of the map from the element that the map is fetching.

So I have my element of the map

```
<div id="map" data-latitude="52.5717929" data-longitude="-2.1400756000000456"></div>
```

and I have set the latitude and longitude on the `div` element. Now inside my `maps.js` file I am trying to fetch the `data-latitude` and the `data-longitude`

How would I do this??

So far I have this:

```
var $map = document.getElementById('map');

var latitude = parseFloat($map.data('latitude'));
var longitude = parseFloat($map.data('longitude'));
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

and all the console is saying is:

> Uncaught TypeError: $map.data is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.data()` method you are using on the element is jQuery syntax. To access a data atributes in pure Javascript you need to use `.dataset.NAME`. Learn more about [accessing the data attributes here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Your code updated:

```js
var $map = document.getElementById('map');

var latitude = parseFloat($map.dataset.latitude);
var longitude = parseFloat($map.dataset.longitude);
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can't believe I was being so dumb :/

Comment: Don't worry, this is usual. It's helpful to have a second pair of eyes :)